# Cosine Annealing Function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I am trying to construct a "Cosine Annealing Function" that produces the figure sketched below.

Note: Not looking for the exact dimensions

[image]

I have tried manipulating $cos(x)$ and $cos^k(x)$, but am completely stumped.

Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps something using the ceil(x) function?

Comment: Try something like [$1 - \Big\lfloor \dfrac{x}{\pi}\Big\rfloor + \cos\left(x - \pi \Big\lfloor \dfrac{x}{\pi}\Big\rfloor\right)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+cos%28x+-+pi+floor%28x+%2F+pi%29%29+-+floor%28x+%2F+pi%29).